# FTP PAM Setup for VSFTPD

Tags: shell, pam, vsftpd

OK. I know this is one of the most asked questions here. But most answers are either telling me to add nologin to allowed shells (nope... not doing that) or disabling SELinux (which i don't have - Ubuntu Server 16.04 RPi3).

Another option is saw was setting my `pam_service_name` to `ftp`. Well this worked! But then I further read that this allows anyone to login as it is just bypassing PAM service. So I thought well lets make a file named `ftp` in the `/etc/pam.d/` directory and work with that.

I filled the file with the following:

```
auth       required     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/security/pam_nologin.so
account    required     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/security/pam_unix.so
password   required     /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/security/pam_unix.so
```

I am missing something, i don't know what. This is the first time I'm messing with PAM so honestly I have no idea what I am doing.

The setup I want is to only allow unix users with `nologin` shell to be authenticated by `vsftpd`.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading a few articles I kinda understad how PAM works.

The files in `/etc/pam.d` are basically list of conditions that are checked when that module/service is being used. So when I set the contents of the file `/etc/pam.d/ftp` to the following:

```
auth    required    pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed
auth    required    pam_succeed_if.so quiet user ingroup ftp
auth    required    pam_succeed_if.so quiet shell = /usr/sbin/nologin
```

I get what I need, i.e. Only UNIX Users that are in **ftp** Group with **nologin** as shell can login.

### Explanation of what each line does:

1. **IF** `USER` in `/etc/ftpusers file` **THEN** *DENY* **ELSE** *ALLOW* and GOTO next RULE
2. **IF** `USER` in `GROUP ftp` **THEN** *ALLOW* and GOTO next RULE **ELSE** *DENY*
3. **IF** `USER`'s `SHELL = /usr/sbin/nologin` **THEN** *ALLOW* GOTO next RULE **ELSE** *DENY*
4. NO NEXT RULE: Allow ACCESS

All the rules are basically `AND'ed` when they are of type **REQUIRED**.

I am linking the guide I followed. I also used Linux Manual Pages for PAM, but not linking them.

Feel free to add anything I have missed. This was my first time with PAM, and I think I love this feature.

Regards!

[An Easy Guide to Linux-PAM by DZONE.com](https://dzone.com/articles/linux-pam-easy-guide)

Comment: When I am my own savior. Funnily I forgot how I did this, luckily I wrote how this works here. So yeah. xD